# IBM MobileFirst platform 8 developer kit license

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Can anyone let me know if IBM MF 8 developer kit is free to use ? I couldn't find proper information on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to clarify:

1. MobileFirst / Worklight Developer Edition - can be freely downloaded from https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/
2. MobileFirst / Worklight Consumer/Enterprise Edition - can be obtained once you have purchased IBM MobileFirst / Worklight.

There is no "license information" in the product itself; you do not register it to a specific name or company.

You should consult with the procurement personnel in your company, or whomever did the IBM MobileFirst / Worklight deal in your company to understand the nature of the deal - renewal date, amount of applications allowed to develop and so on.

You can also contact IBM, but it would make more sense for you to figure this out in-house..

Check This: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/licensing/

Comment: Thanks Gaurab. MobileFirst / Worklight Developer Edition -- To install this in a company machine, we need to contact IBM ?

Comment: Even in company machine, you are going to install developer-kit and that is free.

Comment: Thank you Gaurab.

Comment: Thanks again Gaurab. Will check that.